# How large is the unboundedness locus of a plurisubharmonic function?

Tags: cv.complex-variables

The unboundedness locus L(u) of a plurisubharmonic function u is the set of points x∈X such that u is unbounded in every neighbourhood of x. It always contains the polar locus of u. One knows that the polar locus of a non-trivial psh function is of zero Lebesgue-measure for instance, but is there anything similar known about L(u)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$L(u)$ can be the whole domain. In dimension $1$, take a dense countable
set $\{ z_k\}$ and consider the 
(pluri) subharmonic function $\sum_k a_k\log|z-z_k|$, where $a_k>0$ tend to zero sufficiently fast. In other words, a (pluri) polar set where the (pluri)
subharmonic function equals $-\infty$ can be dense.

Comment: Thanks; so L(u) is as large as can be for a general plurisubharmonic function. I am particurlarly interested in understanding plurisubharmonic functions whose derivatives are locally in $L^2$. Is for this subclass or for other similar sublasses L(u) smaller?

Comment: I think $\sum_k a_k(-\log(-log|z-z_k|))$ does the same job and has derivatives in $L^2$.

Comment: You are right!.